# LeakCanary clean HPROF files

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, hprof

I have a project which integrated `LeakCanary` to detect memory leaks. I know it used `HAHA` to dump memory to `hprof` files to detect leaks.

But every single time I Run app from Android Studio, it trigger dumping process and create a new `hprof` file which has about `60-70` MBs of size.

[image]

By the time it cause my device to full of memory. And when I tried to delete leak logs in Leaks app, some off `hprof` files were NOT cleaned (it has `_pending` in the file name) like the image below. I must manually delete it.

[image]

I'm new to LeakCanary, please help me how can I decrease the frequency of dumping process and how can I clean all the `hprof` files automatically.

Comment: Usually I go to the files and clean `*.hprof` manually, or simple wipe data on emulator (if I run with emulator).

Comment: @AlexeyNikitin I prefer using `adb` :D But this is not the convenience way, right?

Comment: Actually I don't know ;(

Answer (score 0):

i implemented **leakcanary version 1.5.4** and **android studio 3.5.1**

dependencies are

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
```

in emulator, after reproducing memory leaks the **hprof file path** is may be:

```
 /data/user/10/<app_package_name>/files/leakcanary/<filename>.hprof
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest release of LeakCanary: https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/

It should do a much better job of cleaning up hprof files. If not, file a bug on the project

To remove all the existing hprof files at once you can use "adb shell" and use "rm" to delete them all.